# React-Router-Dom: How can this conditional from application state in a Private Route be ignored when navigating from the URL bar in broswer?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, html5-history

I have a Private Route which handles Redirects if a user is not logged in.

```
  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isLoggedIn, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest}
     render={props =>
      isLoggedIn === true
       ? <Component  {...props}/>
       : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/',
          state: {from: props.location}
      }}/>}
  />)
```

And below is it in action with non-protected routes.

```
return (
    <>
    <Switch>
     <Route
      path='/'
      exact
      render={(props) => <LinkNavWithLayout {...props} data={navBars}><Index /></LinkNavWithLayout>} />

     <PrivateRoute
      path='/profile'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      component={() => <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Profile /></LinkNavWithLayout>}
     />

     <PrivateRoute
      path='/dashboard'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      component={()=><LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Dashboard /></LinkNavWithLayout>}/>

     <Route
      path='/login'
      render={(props) => <Login {...props}/>}
     />

     <Route
      path='/register'
      render={() => <Register />}
     />

     {/* <Route component={()=> <h1>Not found</h1>} /> */}
    </Switch>
    </>
  )
 }
```

[image]

So as you can see in the gif I go to the URL bar and try to navigate to the route which has now has access to the rest of the app, but I am still getting redirects?

This is the whole component!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { logInUser, logOutUser } from '../store/index'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import {
 Route,
 Switch,
 Redirect,
 withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'

import LinkNavWithLayout from './LinkNavWithLayout'
import Index from './home'
import Profile from './profile'
import Dashboard from './dashboard'
import Login from './login'
import Register from './register'

class App extends Component {
 static getInitialProps({ isLoggedIn, logInUser, logOutUser }) {

  return { isLoggedIn, logInUser, logOutUser }
 }
 render(){
  const { isLoggedIn } = this.props

 console.log("pages/index this.props ", this.props);
  let navBars = [
   { name: "Home", path: "/"},
   { name: "Profile", path: "/profile"},
   { name: "Dashboard", path: "/dashboard"},
   { name: "Log in", path: "/login"},
   { name: "Register", path: "/register"}
  ];

  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isLoggedIn, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest}
     render={props =>
      isLoggedIn === true
       ? <Component  {...props}/>
       : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/',
          state: {from: props.location}
      }}/>}
  />)


  return (
    <>
    <Switch>
     <Route
      path='/'
      exact
      render={(props) => <LinkNavWithLayout {...props} data={navBars}><Index /></LinkNavWithLayout>} />

     <PrivateRoute
      path='/profile'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      component={() => <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Profile /></LinkNavWithLayout>}
     />

     <PrivateRoute
      path='/dashboard'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      component={()=><LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Dashboard /></LinkNavWithLayout>}/>

     <Route
      path='/login'
      render={(props) => <Login {...props}/>}
     />

     <Route
      path='/register'
      render={() => <Register />}
     />

     <Route component={({ location }) => <p>Sorry but the page <h1>{location.pathname.substring(1)} </h1> Page, Could Not be found</p>} />
    </Switch>
    </>
  )
 }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 const { isLoggedIn, logInUser, logOutUser } = state
 return { isLoggedIn, logInUser, logOutUser }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
 bindActionCreators({ logInUser, logOutUser }, dispatch)

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps
)(withRouter(App))
```

Any help is appreciated greatly!

Comment: when the page loads, what sets `isLoggedIn` ?

Comment: @azium Ahoy! State from Redux.

Comment: @azium I updated the question to share the complete component!

Comment: have you tried console logging `isLoggedIn` inside your App component? maybe it's `false` before it's `true` for a second. or maybe it's truthy but not `=== true` just ideas

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of warnings you have to revisit, asking for some component updates and deprecations. You should also check if isLoggedIn value is available from the beginning,
 since getInitialProps is asynchronous.